# Playback.initialize() method failed in test Agent 2013 installed machine

Tags: visual-studio-2013, mstest, coded-ui-tests

I have created a Winform App to Run Coded UI test scripts recorded in VS2013. Its finely running in the **VS2013[update 4]** installed machine. But when try to run this in Test Agent 2013 installed machine, the exception has been thrown at Playback.Initialize() method , as ***"The following package failed to load: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VSTT\12.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.IE.dll"***

I tried adding this dll in the reference but still the problem persists. I have added the following references. And I am sure that these dlls are available in the mentioned path.

- Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.CodedUITestFramework.dll
  Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll
  Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Common.dll
  Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.dll
  Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.IE.dll
  Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Framework.dll
  Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Playback.dll
  Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.dll*

In that machine, only Test agent 2013 is installed and Configured for "Interactive Process" . Neither Test Controller is installed nor configured with any other test Controller installed machine.

I tried to Run the scripts with MStest using Command Line. Its running.

I have tried a lot by adding/removing many Coded UI dlls. But still the problem persists. Did I miss something? Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried updating Test agent 2013 to update 4?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Its working fine after updating update 4!!!